# Definition review: how to make this geometric definition clearer?

Tags: geometry, definition

In a paper I am writing, I rely on the following definition

> Given a geometric shape $C$ and a family of geometric shapes $S$, The *division number* of $C$ relative to $S$, denoted $DivNum(C,S)$, is the smallest number $n$ such that:
>
> 1. $C$ can be divided to $n$ disjoint pieces from family $S$,  $C=s_{1}\cup...\cup s_{n}$;
> 2. For every $i\in\{1,...,n\}$ and every factor $f\in(0,1)$, the piece $s_{i}$
>      can be scaled (shrinked) by a factor $f$ to a piece $s_{i}^{f}\in S$, such that the remainder $C\setminus s_{i}^{f}$ can be covered by at most $n-1$ shapes from family $S$ (possibly overlapping).

For example: $DivNum(Square,\, Squares)=4$, because any square can be divided to 4 squares in a 2-by-2 grid and each square in this grid can be shrinked by any factor (towards the corner) such that the remainder can be covered by 3 squares. See figure:

[image]

However, it is not true that: $DivNum(1\times 2\ rectangle,\, Squares)=2$, because, although a $1\times 2$ rectangle can be divided to two disjoint squares, if one of the squares is shrinked to a smaller square, the remainder can no longer be covered by a single square:

[image]

I feel that the definition is not clear/formal enough. How would you improve it to make it clearer and more formal? (I hope these two requests are not contradictory..)

Comment: One of the parts I find confusing is the way that you are shrinking the shape. Is the idea that for every $s_i$, no matter how much you shrink it by, i.e., dilating by any scalar $\lambda \in (0, 1]$, it can then be translated somewhere within $C$ so that there exist $n-1$ of the $S$-shapes (possibly with overlap) that can be unioned with $\lambda s_i$ to cover $C$?

Comment: @BenjaminDickman The shrinking is indeed the part with which I have a problem. I don't mean necessarily a dilation. What I mean is: for every nonatomic measure defined on $s_i$ and every fraction $f\in(0,1)$, there is a subset of $s_i$ with measure $f\cdot measure(s_i)$, such that it can be unioned with $n-1$ $S$-shapes to cover $C$. But, I prefer to keep the definition purely geometrical and not use measure-related terms.